# Calling facebook marketing api /insights endpoint returns an empty array data [] for sandbox marketing account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm using facebook's graphe api tool to test their marketing api, i ve created an ad campaign, and an adset to that campaign, and then an ad to a post i ve created using the create post api too and set its adset to the adset i previously created, and i ve also made sure that the status of the capmpaign/adset/ad is set to ACTIVE, and then i have tried calling all these 3:

graph.facebook.com/v6.0/CAMPAIGN_ID/insights

graph.facebook.com/v6.0/ADSET_ID/insights

graph.facebook.com/v6.0/AD_ID/insights

I get a response that contains an empty array.

```
data[]
```

Note that I am using a sandbox account id for this hence my question would be: does facebook generate some simulated insights on a sandbox account, if so: what am I doing wrong? also I have seen a solution saying that i need to get page_insights permission in order to have that, but at the same time when I go to the sandbox account section there is no such thing as permissions so I assumed I have permissions to do anything since they claimed that the sandbox account provides identical functionalities as a real marketing account.

Best Regards

Comment: Seems like you might be getting back an empty array because there are no insights for whatever fields you are selecting. Sandbox accounts don't always return data for all fields. What fields are you trying to select?

Comment: i have not specified any field

Comment: Do you get any data if you specify a field? Like 'impressions'

Comment: @CHARGUIFahd were you able to solve this? I am having exactly the same problem.